# Pass Dict in scrapy start urls

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, dictionary, scrapy

I have a Pandas DataFrame which I want to use as Scrapy Start URL, The function get_links opens an xlsx to DataFrame, This has a Column LINK which I want to run the spider on,

I convert it to dict using,

```
dictdf = df.to_dict(orient='records']
```

I know these links can be achieved by url = url['LINK'] but what I want to do is pass the whole dict into the scrapy output

```
 dictdf = {'Data1':'1','Data2':'2','LINK':'www.link.com',.....,'Datan':'n'}


# start urls
def start_requests(self):
    urls = get_links()


    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url['LINK'], callback=self.parse)
```

My question is is there any way to pass the whole dict into parse() so yielding the dictdf in output as well?
and output of scrapy be,

```
    {'ScrapedData1':'d1','Data1':'1','Data2':'2','LINK':'www.link.com',.....,'Datan':'n'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to carry over some data from `start_requests` method.

To do that you can user `Request.meta` attribute:

```
def start_requests(self):
    data = [{
        'url': 'http://httpbin.org',
        'extra_data': 'extra',
    }]
    for item in data:
        yield Request(item['url'], meta={'item': item})

def parse(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    # {'url': 'http://httpbin.org', 'extra_data': 'extra'}
```